# Bootstrap 5 Navbar Dropdown won't Open on Hover

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am making a website with Bootstrap 5 and I am trying to get the navbar dropdown to open on hover by adding my custom CSS but when I add the CSS the navbar still won't hover. However some reason, the code works in insolation because when I was entering the code in the code snippet and I ran it, it worked, but it doesn't on my website.

### Index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Your awesome title:</title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_bridgetown/static/js/main.96ffffaea92690057bfb.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white py-3">
    <div class="container">
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="C:\Users\NewMayoAyo\Documents\_Dev\projects\Bootstrap\assets\logo-topnav.png" alt=" Name" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
    </a>

    <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
    <button
        type="button"
        class="navbar-toggler"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navmenu"
    >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
    </button>
    <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

    <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
            <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
    </div>

</nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->
  </body>
</html>
```

### Index.css

```css
#dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```css
#dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Your awesome title:</title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_bridgetown/static/js/main.96ffffaea92690057bfb.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white py-3">
    <div class="container">
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="C:\Users\NewMayoAyo\Documents\_Dev\projects\-Bootstrap\assets\logo-topnav.png" alt=" Name" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
    </a>

    <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
    <button
        type="button"
        class="navbar-toggler"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navmenu"
    >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
    </button>
    <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

    <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
            <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
    </div>

</nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see it working perfect on my Mac using Safari in both mobile version and desktop version

Comment: Works in Chrome, too. It's a pretty workable code. If it refuses to work when hosting the website, it's just an issue referencing the custom styles. Hosting something on your own server, especially if that "something" has any server logic, is a very tedious and error-prone work.

Comment: @SNBS I'm not hosting it yet I using it locally in chrome

Comment: You mean it works in Stack Overflow code snippet but doesn't work in Chrome? But that's obviously impossible, how can the behavior of an embedded page differ from behavior of the same HTML not embedded into another document (especially such a simple snippet without forms, scripts, iframes etc)

Comment: @SNBS I don't know what's happening because when I open the HTML in Chrome the dropdown doesn't work but if you run my code snippet it does

Comment: Maybe you use such an old version of Chrome? Maybe try injecting the `display: block` style into your document directly using `<style>`?

Comment: @SNBS can you please show me what you mean?

Comment: I mean a construction like `<style>{style in index.css}</style>` in the `head` of your `index.html`, that would ensure that the issue isn't in references between files

Answer (score 2):

If the code is working when isolated from your website, there is most likely something on your website that is taking priority.

The first thing I would try would be to include !important,

```css
#dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block !important;
}
```

If other CSS is taking priority over your code, !important will stop that.

Also, if you move the style tag below the link tag that loads in the Bootstrap CSS, it may resolve your issue.

Comment: when reading this answer, you asking guy, take a look at your server files, check if the CHMOD is correct to execute files, because the code is fine and this answer will improve it too. But it smells like corrupt files or permission failure. But I will vote up this answer anyway

Comment: @Marcus Petersen I tried ```!important``` but it didn't work. I don't know what CHMOD is but I don't think there is something wrong with the directory. I am also using a windows system btw

Comment: Upload your code to Codepen here www.codepen.io and you will see your own code is working fine

Comment: @Marcus Petersen You are right, so how do I fix it so that it works on my actual website, thank you.

Comment: @PFL First, get the code as a codependent like Kamikaza suggested. It makes debugging these much easier compared to SO's awful thing.